# Why in my react app JWT token not available on the first sign in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

Why is that when I load the application and/or reload the page then try signing in to the app, the JWT token is not available to me on the first try:

[image]

But if I logout and sign back in, I see that now the token is available to me:

[image]

I've double checked my code and can't seems to figure out what causes this issue

**api_helper.js**

```
import axios from "axios"
import accessToken from "./jwt-token-access/accessToken"

const token = accessToken();
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080";

const axiosApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    // 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
  },
})

axiosApi.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';

axiosApi.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => Promise.reject(error)
)

export async function get(url, config = {}) {
  return await axiosApi
    .get(url, { ...config })
    .then(response => response.data)
}

export async function post(url, data, config = {}) {
  return axiosApi
    .post(url, { ...data }, { ...config })
    .then(response => response.data)
}

export async function put(url, data, config = {}) {
  return axiosApi
    .put(url, { ...data }, { ...config })
    .then(response => response.data)
}

export async function del(url, config = {}) {
  return await axiosApi
    .delete(url, { ...config })
    .then(response => response.data)
}
```

**auth_helper.js**

```
import { post, get, put } from "./api_helper";
const getLoggedInUser = () => {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('authUser');
    if (user) return JSON.parse(user);
    return null;
}

//is user is logged in
const isUserAuthenticated = () => {
    return getLoggedInUser() !== null;
}

export { 
    getLoggedInUser, 
    isUserAuthenticated
}
```

**accessToken.js**

```
const accessToken = () => {
  const obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authUser"));
  
  if (obj && obj.token) {
    return obj.token;
  } else {
    return "";
  }
};

export default accessToken;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer **to the question you asked earlier** today and subsequently deleted, in case it is still helpful. (The question was titled "How to loop and display an array of objects into two different div contains like a panel side by side?")

The snippet has an `extractDisplayTexts` function and an `addChildrenToRightDiv` function to populate the divs, and takes advantage of [the flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#the_flex_model) to style them as you had suggested.

Happy coding.

```js
const
  // Gets data, extracts strings, and identifies DOM container
  json = getInput(),
  texts = extractDisplayTexts(json),
  outer = document.getElementById("container");
  
// Creates left div (and puts first string in it)
const left = document.createElement("div");
left.textContent = texts[0];

// Creates right div (giving it `flex-direction: column`)
const right = document.createElement("div");
right.classList.add("column");
right.classList.add("separator-at-left");

// Makes column's children (and puts remaining strings in it)
addChildrenToRightDiv();

// Adds both divs to the DOM
container.appendChild(left);
container.appendChild(right);

function addChildrenToRightDiv(){
  const otherTexts = texts.slice(1);
  for(let text of otherTexts){
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.textContent = text;
    right.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}

function extractDisplayTexts(data){
  strings = [];
  for(let path of data.tableData.datapaths){
    const
      [header, label] = path.row,
      headerText = header.header,
      num = header.value,
      labelText = label.label,
      date = label.value,
      displayText =`${headerText}${num}, ${labelText} ${date}`;
    strings.push(displayText);
  }
  return strings;
}

function getInput(){
  return {
    "tableData": {
      "datapaths": [
        {
          "row": [
            { "header": "Initial Seq #: ", "value": "5" },
            { "label": "Issued", "value": "Dec 1, 2015" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "row": [
            { "header": "Initial Seq #: ", "value": "3" },
            { "label": "Issued", "value": "Sept 25, 2014" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "row": [
            { "header": "Initial Seq #: ", "value": "5" },
            { "label": "Issued", "value": "Feb 10, 2013" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
}
```

```css
div { padding: 5px; }
.separator-at-left{ border-left: 3px solid blue; }
.row { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }
.column { display: flex; flex-direction: column; } /* vertical layout */
```

```html
<div id="container" class="row"></div>
```

Comment: I am really grateful for your solution Cat. Thank you so much for the help on my previous question. This is great!